# Ajax запрос работает только для одного элемента в шаблоне Django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

У меня есть видео на сайте (на Django). Каждое видео, находится в модальном окне и под видео есть возможность добавить комментарии. Я сделал добавление комментариев с помощью Ajax и все работает нормально, но только для первого видео. Когда я, пытаюсь добавить комментарий на следующие видео, Django мне выдаёт ошибку:

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ziotyr/PycharmProjects/HROTIAS/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ziotyr/PycharmProjects/HROTIAS/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view videoHosting.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[28/Feb/2020 21:52:42] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 63259
```

Пишет, что мои представления возвращают `None`, а не `HttpResponse`, но почему-то для первого видео всё отрабатывает нормально.

Вот сам код views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Xvideo, Comment

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        response_data = {}

        comment_under_the_video = Comment(
            user=request.user,
            video=Xvideo.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('video')),
            content_text=request.POST.get('comment')
        )
        comment_under_the_video.save()

        response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
        response_data['user'] = comment_under_the_video.user.username
        response_data['comment'] = comment_under_the_video.content_text
        response_data['date'] = comment_under_the_video.pub_date

        return JsonResponse(response_data)

    if request.method == "GET":
        file_list = Xvideo.objects.all()

        context = {'videos': file_list}

        return render(request, 'videoHosting/index.html', context)
```

Вот код с Ajax запросом:

```
// Отправка и добавление комментариев
$('#commentForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    let csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');


    console.log("create post is working!");
    $.ajax({
        url: "/",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            comment: $('#id_content_text').val(),
            video: $('#video').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken'),
        },


        success: function (json) {
            $('#id_content_text').val('');
            $("#talk").prepend("<li><strong>" + json.comment + "</strong> - <em> " + json.user + "</em> - <span> " + json.date + "</span></li>");
            console.log("success");
        },


        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(`Error ` + xhr + ' ' + errmsg + ' ' + err)
        }
    });
});
```

А вот код HTML шаблона:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Главная</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'videoHosting/css/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark row">
            <div class="col-1">
                <a href="{% url 'videoHosting:index' %}">
                    <svg class="bi bi-camera-video text-white-50" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                         fill="currentColor"
                         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M4.667 5.5c-.645 0-1.167.522-1.167 1.167v6.666c0 .645.522 1.167 1.167 1.167h6.666c.645 0 1.167-.522 1.167-1.167V6.667c0-.645-.522-1.167-1.167-1.167H4.667zM2.5 6.667C2.5 5.47 3.47 4.5 4.667 4.5h6.666c1.197 0 2.167.97 2.167 2.167v6.666c0 1.197-.97 2.167-2.167 2.167H4.667A2.167 2.167 0 012.5 13.333V6.667z"
                              clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M13.25 7.65l2.768-1.605a.318.318 0 01.482.263v7.384c0 .228-.26.393-.482.264l-2.767-1.605-.502.865 2.767 1.605c.859.498 1.984-.095 1.984-1.129V6.308c0-1.033-1.125-1.626-1.984-1.128L12.75 6.785l.502.865z"
                              clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedCountent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedCountent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedCountent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li class="nav-item active linki">
                            <a href="{% url 'account_logout' %}"
                               class="nav-link text-center btn btn-dark a-nav">Выход</a>
                        </li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item active linki">
                            <a href="{% url 'account_signup' %}" class="nav-link text-center btn btn-dark a-nav">Регистрация</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a href="{% url 'account_login' %}"
                               class="nav-link text-center btn btn-dark a-nav2">Вход</a>
                        </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 search">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2 btn-input" placeholder="Поиск" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 btn-search">Найти</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="main-content my-4">
            <div class="row">
                {% for video in videos %}
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow modal_cursor" data-target="#exampleModal-{{ forloop.counter }}"
                             data-toggle="modal">
                            <span class="text-center">{{ video.name }}</span>
                            <img class="card-img-top"
                                 data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail"
                                 alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]" style="height: 225px; width: 100%; display: block;"
                                 src="{{ video.video_splash_screen.url }}"
                                 data-holder-rendered="true">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                                    <div class="btn-group col-5">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                                data-target="#exampleModal">
                                            Открыть
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <small class="text-muted">{{ video.pub_date }}</small>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-{{ forloop.counter }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                         aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{{ video.name }}</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="video">
                                        <video class="video_elem col-sm" controls name="media">
                                            <source src="{{ video.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                                        </video>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="row justify-content-between">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                    data-target="#multiCollapseExample1" aria-expanded="false"
                                                    aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">
                                                Описание
                                            </button>
                                            <div>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                                        data-target="#multiCollapseExample2" aria-expanded="false"
                                                        aria-controls="multiCollapseExample2">
                                                    Комментарии
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>
                                            {#                 DESCRIPTION VIDEO                 #}
                                            <div class="mt-2">
                                                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                                        {{ video.description }}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            {#                COMMENTS                        #}
                                            <div class="mt-2">
                                                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample2">
                                                    <div class="card card-body">
                                                        <div class="body_comment">
                                                            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                                                                <form method="POST" class="commentForm"
                                                                      id="commentForm">
                                                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                                                    <input id="video" type="hidden" name="video"
                                                                           value="{{ video.id }}">
                                                                    <p>
                                                                        <label for="id_content_text">Комментарий:</label>
                                                                        <textarea name="content_text" cols="40"
                                                                                  rows="10"
                                                                                  maxlength="1000" required=""
                                                                                  id="id_content_text"></textarea>
                                                                    </p>
                                                                    <input type="submit">
                                                                </form>
                                                            {% else %}
                                                                <p>Хочешь коментить, зарегайся на сайте</p>
                                                            {% endif %}
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="footer_comment">
                                                            {% for comment in video.comment_set.all reversed %}
                                                                <ul id="talk">
                                                                    <li>{{ comment.content_text }}</li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            {% endfor %}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>


    <footer class="footer mt-auto py-3 justify-content-end navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</span>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>


<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="{% static 'videoHosting/js/script.js' %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Посмотри в инспекторе во вкладке `Network` запрос, который уходит и ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не используйте на странице повторяющиеся `id`.

```
$('.commentForm').on('submit', function (e) {
  ...
  var $form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      comment: $form.find('.content_text').val(),
      video: $form.find('.video').val(),
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')
    },
    success: function (json) {
      $form.find('.content_text').val('');
      ...


<form method="POST" class="commentForm">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="video" type="hidden" name="video" value="{{ video.id }}">
  <p>
    <label>Комментарий:<br/>
      <textarea name="content_text" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="1000" required="" 
        class="content_text"></textarea>
    </label>
  </p>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```